# Font change in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, fonts

i want to use “Comfortaa” font in my application,to all page(like default font).i used the font using url.
like this:

```
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa');
</style>
```

in .scss

```
font-family: 'Comfortaa'
```

but application is in offline the font did not work in my aaplication.how i can use the font in both offline and online condition.
when app is in offline it shows a italic type font.
like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First download and put the folder in src/assets/fonts and then in your theme folder write:

```
 $font-path: "../assets/fonts";
 @font-face {
 font-family: GlobalFont;
 src: url("../assets/fonts/Comfortaa/Comfortaa.ttf");
 }

 body, span, button, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ion-item, ion-title {
```

font-family: 'GlobalFont' !important;
  }

Answer (score 1):

```
For add custom font in a application 
Do following step:
```

Add custom font to assets/fonts folder

Add following code to app.scss file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'San Francisco Light';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('../assets/fonts/SanFranciscoDisplay-Regular.otf');
}

After In theme/variables.scss file

add variable name
like this:`enter code here`
$font-family-ios-base: "San Francisco Light";
$font-family-md-base:  "roboto";
```